# Powershell how to encrypt connectionstring to database

Tags: database, powershell, database-connection

I have a powershell script that connects to a database:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=10.10.10.1;Initial Catalog=my_database;User Id=my_username;Password=my_password;"
```

But I don't want the plaintext password to be hardcoded into the script.

So, I tried the following:

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\PS\cred.txt
$password = get-content C:\PS\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "my_username",$password
```

And, I replaced the connection string with

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=10.10.10.1;Initial Catalog=my_database;$credentials;"
```

But I am getting numerous errors.

This script is run on a nightly basis, so it must get the password of the database automatically.

EDIT:

Below are the errors:

```
Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 46." At C:\sandbox\script.ps1:75 char:7
    + $conn. <<<< ConnectionString = "Server=10.10.10.1;Initial Catalog=my_database;$credentials;"
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

and

```
Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 46." At C:\sandbox\script.ps1:82 char:14
    + $conn_update. <<<< ConnectionString = "Server=10.10.10.1;Initial Catalog=my_database;$credentials;"
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException   Creating and executing the SQL Query at 8/26/2013 10:28:38 AM
```

and finally

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." At C:\sandbox\script.ps1:98 char:11
    + $conn.Open <<<< ()
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the first error

First try this in ps console

```
PS C:\>"server=server10;Initail Catalog=database;$credentials"
server=server10;Initail Catalog=database;System.Management.automation.PSCredential
```

and sql server doesn't expect the connection string with System.Management.Automation.PSCredential and it need it in a format of user id="myusername"; password="password"

so do this instead. First retrieve username and password from $credentials object and store them in variable and put that variable in the connectionstring.

```
$username = $credentials.UserName
$password = $credentials.GetNetworkCredentail().Password

PS C:\>"server=server10;Initial Catalog=database;user id=$username;password=$password"
server=server10;Initial Catalog=database;user id=my_username;password=sdfsjci34929
```